Show settlement labels on a map based on population and settlement density in different areas
Is it possible to show settlement labels based on population and settlement density in QGIS 3.36?
I have two layers of settlements:
Biggest Cities Layer: This layer contains the largest cities, which are always visible on the map.
Less Populated Settlements Layer: This layer includes smaller settlements, and I want to show these based on the following criteria:

Population: Higher population settlements should always be prioritized.

Area Settlement Density: In areas with many settlements, I need to hide even large ones (with populations of 100,000 or more). Conversely, in areas with fewer settlements, I want to display even small towns (with populations of 5,000).


Both layers use rule-based symbology (dot size based on population) and labels (text size based on population). I also need to show symbol only when label will be visible.
Is there possible way to achieve this?


You can create a field named "Settlement Category" and paste this expression , which will give 3 different ID's (0,1,2) based on your criteria.
~
case
when 0 <=  "population" AND "population"  <= 5  AND 0<= "DENSITY" AND "DENSITY" <=5 then 0
when 5 <= "population" AND"population"  <= 10 AND 4<= "DENSITY" AND "DENSITY"<=10 then 1
when 10 <=  "population" AND  10<= "DENSITY"
then 2
END
~
The values 0,5,10 are indicated , you will decide the value boundaries.
In case that you dont want all of those 3 ID's to be at the same field, you can create 3 separate fields named for example "First Category" , "Second Category" , "Third Category" and paste at the expression of each one separately each expression.
For example at the "First Category" field :
~
case
when 0 <=  "population" AND "population"  <= 5  AND 0<= "DENSITY" AND "DENSITY" <=5 then 0
END
~
etc.
Finally you will have 3 different fields where each one will have an ID based on your criteria.
Hope that helped (if i understood your question correctly).
